# TypeScript Arry Of Objects Search

Tags: javascript

Hi in my case I was recieve array of random strings that's are part of country name.After that I need to check in Array any country name match.I am not sure but my solution looks to slow and simple.How can I make search faster while using typescript.I mean I loop every part for every country.

```
for(let name of counriesNames){
    for(let country of countries){
         if(country.name.contains(name))
                do something
```

Comment: share sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify to a single for-loop with the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) array methods:

```js
for(let country of countries
    .filter(country => counriesNames.some(name => country.name.contains(name)) {

    // do something

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try <s>[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)</s> [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
    counriesNames.map((name) => {
      if ( countries.find(country => country.name === name) ) {
        //do something
        console.log(name);
      }
    });
```

EDIT:

```
counriesNames.forEach((name) => {
  if ( countries.find(country => country.name === name) ) {
    //do something
    console.log(name);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why `map` and not `foreach`? Unless you want to return the result set.